# How to move an image on a mobile phone with my finger?

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm just getting started with Mobile Phone development and want to know how do I get an image (of a rock) to follow my fingers as I move it around the screen.

Also, how can I 'push' the rock and let it roll a few pixels?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the MouseDown and MouseMove events. On MouseDown you'll want to capture the current x and y co-ordinates of the mouse:

```
private Point trackPoint;
trackPoint= new Point(x, y);
```

On MouseMove, you'll need to calculate the differences between the original points x and y and the new mouse positions x and y (where `e` is the EventArgs of the MouseMove event):

```
int xDiff = trackPoint.X - e.X;
int yDiff = trackPoint.Y - e.Y;
```

Then update the tracking position

```
trackPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
```

Then, move the Image by the xDiff and yDiff:

```
Image.Location = new Point(Image.Location.X - xDiff, Image.Location.Y - yDiff);
```

This is completely untested and I don't guarantee the above will work as-is, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?